How to test client behavior when a certificate revocation status is "Unknown"
I'm trying to test the behavior we see on our client application when it connects to a server and the certificate revocation status of the server certificate comes back as "Unknown".
Testing a revoked certificate is easy as there are test sites out there such as https://revoked.badssl.com/ however I can't seem to find anything that will help me test an Unknown status.
Is there any site out there that I can use to test this behavior, or a simple test I could setup myself?
